# Datatables not aligning properly when page is resized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have two data tables in my MVC view. I am able to display them side by side next to each other.  But when I resize the browser (restore down), the data tables are overlapping each other instead of one below the other.  How do I make the data tables next to each other when the browser is full size and one below the other when I resize the browser?  I am using Bootstrap 4 in MVC razor view.

Note: This is my first time attaching a snippet in stackoverflow.  So please bear with me if it is not correct!

[Tables aligned next to each other when on full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjIV5.jpg)

[tables squeezing next to each other when resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8oDB.jpg)

```css
.dataTables_wrapper {
  border: thin solid #808080;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  @if (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.recentprojects) > 0) {



  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:burlywood">
              @Html.DisplayName("My Recent Projects")
            </th>


          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer">
              @Html.DisplayName("Projects")
            </th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="projects">
          @foreach (var item in ViewBag.recentprojects) {
          <tr>
            <td class="col">
              <a href="#">  @item.ProjectCode</a>: @item.ProjectTitle
            </td>
          </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>



  }

  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
  </div>

  @if ((ViewBag.Leader is true) && (Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.teamprojects) > 0)) {


  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="data1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:burlywood">
              @Html.DisplayName("My Team's Recent Projects")
            </th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer">
              @Html.DisplayName("Projects")
            </th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="projects">
          @foreach (var item in ViewBag.teamprojects) {
          <tr>
            <td class="col">
              <a href="#"> @item.ProjectCode</a>: @item.ProjectTitle
            </td>

          </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  }


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used Bootstrap. Try implementing the grid model on your elements. That is much more responsive and you can set the responsivity to various screen sizes like very small, small, medium and large.
Here's a link for reference as to which classes to use according to the screen size :
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Thank you Aniket.  I tried using "Col-xs-6" instead of width property.  The behavior is still the same.  When I resize the browser, the table overlaps instead of aligning below each other.

Comment: you have to use a lot of them simultaneously to tell it about the size it should take. Example: class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 "

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap you need too implement grid model on your elements and responsive table. grid model give the responsiveness of various screen sizes like very small, small, medium and large. And responsive table make you table responsive. So your code look link below --

```
<div class="panel-body" id="ProjectReq">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:burlywood">
                                My Recent Projects
                            </th>


                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer">
                                Projects
                            </th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="projects">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col">
                                Test Project
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="data1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead style="background-color:lightgray">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer;background-color:burlywood">
                                My Team's Recent Projects
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" style="cursor:pointer">
                                Projects
                            </th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="projects">

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col">
                                Test Project 1
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashiquzzaman.  I modified my code to include the "table-responsive" class outside the "table" class.  The result is still the same.  However, when I removed the "width:39em" from my wrapper stylesheet, it no longer overlaps.  But still, the table doesn't align one below the other when page is resized.  Instead, the table shrinks side by side with a horizontal scroll bar on each.  I am trying to make them align one below the other!

Comment: @incorrigible r u use the "row" class? and also please send a screenshot

Comment: I have modified the code snippet to the actual code am using now.  I have included the two snapshots as well as to how it appears when on full screen and how it appears when screen is resized.  As you can see, they still align next to one another.  I want it to align one below the other when resized. Thanks for your help!